# Migration from PostreSQL to MySQL using MySQL Workbench trows errors

Tags: postgresql, mysql-workbench, database-migration, postgresql-8.1

I am trying to migrate a PostreSQL database to a local MySQL server using MySQL Workbench. I have set both connections, tested them and succeded, selected schemas to migrate and clicked next.

However, it always ends up at Reverse engineer selected schemas, where it keeps getting some errors. The image(s) below shows them all.

I have found some suggestions to edit some files (db_postgresql_re_grt.py), but none of them worked (even after restarting MySQL Workbench).

PostgreSQL version is 8.1.23

[image: Error]

Complete message log:
[image: Message log]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you found a bug in migration wizard. Please fill [bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com), and (if you can) attach your database to it (you can make it private, that only Oracle employees can see it).

Comment: Note: pg_enum was changed *somewhere* after pg-8.1, (and again in pg-9.3) (and 8.1 is a very old, unsupported version, best migration path would be to first upgrade to a recent postgres version)